# Tags with an underscore cause failure with BeautifulSoup selector

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sites>
  <site>
    <name>Default</name>
    <url_namespace>default</url_namespace>
  </site>
</sites>
```

Soup info:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
soup.select('url_namespace')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "url_namespace"
```

How does one select an xml tag, or and id which contains an underscore?

Comment: soup.find('url_namespace') [find](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=select#find) doesn't work?

Comment: @Scott I need the select option. Find only returns a single instance. I could use find all, but I need it in the structure of findAll('sites url_namespace'), which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest lxml just because this could be done with a simple XPath, but just for the fun of showing how to select an invalid CSS selector... well, you actually don't. There are a couple of things that can be done, one of which is to replace the offensive tag with perhaps a `div` tag with a specific class, so you can select it.

However, one really hackish way of doing this really quickly is to just change the `name` property of each element you find.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

data = """
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <sites>
    <site>
    <name>Default</name>
        <url_namespace>default1</url_namespace>
        <url_namespace>default2</url_namespace>
        <url_namespace>default3</url_namespace>
        <url_namespace>default4</url_namespace>
    </site>
    </sites>
    """
soup = bsoup(data)

elements = soup.find_all("url_namespace")
for element in elements:
    element.name = "urlnamespace"
print soup
```

The above changes the soup to the following:

```
<html><body><sites>
<site>
<name>Default</name>
<urlnamespace>default1</urlnamespace>
<urlnamespace>default2</urlnamespace>
<urlnamespace>default3</urlnamespace>
<urlnamespace>default4</urlnamespace>
</site>
</sites>
</body></html>
```

Adding the following codeblock to the above code...

```
targets = soup.select("urlnamespace")
for target in targets:
    print target.get_text()
```

... gives you the following result:

```
default1
default2
default3
default4
```

Not really the prettiest way, but it works. Out of sheer curiosity, though, why the need to select the tag this way? `find_all` works on the tag, as you can see above.

Anyway, let us know if this works.

Comment: I could use find_all, if there was a way to only select items under a specific parent. Didn't see any way to do that using find_all

Comment: Hm, while I think your wording is somewhat confusing, my curiosity is still piqued. If you mean you want to access an elements inside the collection of elements returned by `find_all`, there's a way to do that. But I have the feeling this is something you already know. Can you kindly post a bigger or more accurate dataset we can work on? :)